# What means the notation T&&.. (2 dot)?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Reading the C++ 11 of Stroustrup, at chapter about variadic template there is a notation: `T&&..` with only 2 dots. I don't understand why is not with full ellipsis `...`
Could you teach what it means?
Thank you.

EDIT: context is:

28.6.3 Forwarding

```
template<typename F, typename...T>
void call(F&& f, T&&.. t)
{
f(forward<T>(t)...)
}
```

Comment: post the context. Without the context I can only assume it is a typo.

Comment: Perhaps you could quote some context, and also include the page number (and the edition/printing of the book you're looking at).

Comment: That sounds like he meant 3 dots, never heard of 2 dots in C++11

Comment: if that is in actual code, it means someone was overpaid when they signed off as proof reading that section of the document.

Comment: it is a typo. It should have been `T&&...`

Comment: That might be a new erratum: see what you can find under [Errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html) and in related pages, but I didn't see it.  You could report it to Bjarne if it seems to be new. Or there again, it might be a known problem — see (one of) the answer(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a misprint. The edition I am looking at has:

```
template<typename F, typename ... T>
void call(F&& f, T&&... t)
{
   f(forward<T>(t)...);
}
```